# R assignments inside functions

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, variable-assignment

```
library(tidyverse)
xy <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)

plotfunc <- function(data, x, y){
  print(
    ggplot(data, aes_(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
      geom_line()
  )
}
plotfunc(xy, xvar, yvar)
```

The function above works fine. The function below does not. How do I make the proper assignments shown below? I know they don't *really* do anything but I wan't to start getting my syntax correct anyway.

```
plotfunc <- function(data, x, y){
  rng <- range(substitute(x), na.rm = TRUE)
  rescale <- (substitute(x) - rng[1]) / (rng[2] - rng[1])
  print(
    ggplot(data, aes_(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
      geom_line()
  )
}
plotfunc(xy, xvar, yvar)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evaluate `xvar` in the context of the `data.frame` :

```
plotfunc <- function(data, x, y){
  rng <- range(eval(substitute(x),envir = data), na.rm = TRUE)
  rescale <- (eval(substitute(x),envir = data) - rng[1]) / (rng[2] - rng[1])
  print(
    ggplot(data, aes_(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
      geom_line()
  )
}
plotfunc(xy, xvar, yvar)
```

Comment: For programming with the `tidyverse` you might be interested by this resource: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using more of the tidyverse style of programming:

```
library(tidyverse)
xy <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)


plotfunc2 <- function(data, x, y){
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  rng <- data %>% summarise(r1 = range(!!x, na.rm = TRUE)[1],
                             r2 = range(!!x, na.rm = TRUE)[2]) 
  new_data <- data %>% mutate(rescale = (!!x - rng$r1)/(rng$r2 - rng$r1)) 
  ggplot(data, aes(x = !!x, y = !!y)) +
      geom_line()
}
plotfunc2(xy, xvar, yvar)
```

Comment: I would suggest select / pull / range (called only one time), instead of summarize